# Azure AD B2C - Callback Method Issue in Android

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

**Background**

I'm trying to implement Azure AD B2C SSO in my Android application. For this purpose, I'm using the following documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-android-app/

The AppAuth library, which is mentioned in the above documentation can be found at the below URL.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth/tree/master/
https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android

**Current situation**

Everything worked well, and I can see the login page from the Azure as well.

**Issue**

When I put the correct login credentials, the control doesn't return to the callback method.
The callback method mentioned in the documentation is `onTokenRequestCompleted`

[image]

**Questions**
Are we on right track to achieve SSO in the Android using Azure AD B2C?

- If no, please guide us for the correct library and sample app.
- If yes, kindly advise the possible reasons when a callback may not be called?

Thanks

Comment: You are on the right track on choosing the correct libraries. Regarding the callback you are mentioned please check the [documentation](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/docs/latest/net/openid/appauth/AuthorizationService.html#performTokenRequest-net.openid.appauth.TokenRequest-net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback-) for more information

Comment: Seems my issue related to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357179/authentication-failed-com-microsoft-identity-client-exception-msalclientexcepti

@Ans can u guide me

Answer (score 0):

(Moving form comments to answered)

You are on the right track on choosing the correct libraries. Regarding the callback you are mentioned please check the [documentation](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/docs/latest/net/openid/appauth/AuthorizationService.html#performTokenRequest-net.openid.appauth.TokenRequest-net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback-) for more information

Comment: Yes, we have implemented these callback. There was another issue where we were missing the exposing the API. We completed the setup and it worked well.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Thanks for the confirmation @Ans

Comment: @Raghavendra beldona

Can you Guide me 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357179/authentication-failed-com-microsoft-identity-client-exception-msalclientexcepti