# Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: Missing required tokens of type: {0}

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, access-token, azure-ad-msal

Implemented Azure B2C login.

Suddenly app getting this error.
unable to find where the issue is.
can anyone help

we are using below source:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java

[image]

[image]

**Below code using for Generate KeyHash**

```
public static void getKeyHash(Context mAppContext){
        final String packageName = mAppContext.getPackageName();
        try {
            final PackageInfo info = mAppContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (final Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                messageDigest.update(signature.toByteArray());
                final String signatureHash = Base64.encodeToString(messageDigest.digest(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Log.i("Utils", "signatureHash-->"+signatureHash);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Utils", "Unexpected error in verifyRedirectUriWithAppSignature()", e);
        }

    }
```

**Scope having Granted permission and same scope URL using in android code**

[image]

***I forgot offline_access permission
after added this permission app working***

Comment: Hi, might I ask where did youadd  the offline_acces permission ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and resolved it successfully.

It is because you didn't do the admin consent for the API permission on Azure portal.

Please see [this line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/blob/f3627771277e9e61d2058c0496f5c732706fd10c/app/src/main/java/com/azuresamples/msalandroidapp/B2CConfiguration.java#L94) in the official sample code.

```
public static List<String> getScopes() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read");
    }
```

This sample sets the scope as `https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read` so that it can acquire an access token for this API.

Firstly, you should add an app registration which represents your web API and expose the API by following [Quickstart: Configure an application to expose a web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis).

Secondly, you need to add the API permission in your client app registration (its client id is configured in `auth_config_b2c.json` file) by following [Quickstart: Configure a client application to access a web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis).

Now the most important thing is doing the admin consent in Azure portal:

[image]

You can click on the permission in Azure portal to see it.

[image]

Modify the scope in code to your own scope/permission.

```
public static List<String> getScopes() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "https://allentest001.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read");
    }
```

With all the settings configured, we can acquire the access token after signing in.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer.
Scope permission is proper. updated screenshot in my question.
Can you please check it.

Comment: i am generating keyhash using below command

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\Samples\TaazaDelivery\taaza_android\gradle\taazakeystore.jks" | "C:\Users\nravva\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\nravva\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64

xSLzBBuLJunOQPB89rtzM54FXx4=

is it correct ??